# Extracting from the Message in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way but this is what I have and what I am getting:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='security'; id=4663;} | ?{$_.message -match "DELETE" -And $_.message -match "C:\\Shares\\Share" -And $_.message -NotMatch ".tmp|~\\$"} | Select -expand Message
```

I get this output:

```
Subject:
        Security ID:            S-1-5-21-
        Account Name:           name
        Account Domain:         domain
        Logon ID:               0x9CD04EC

Object:
        Object Server:          Security
        Object Type:            File
        Object Name:            C:\Shares\
        Handle ID:              0x5504
        Resource Attributes:    S:AI

Process Information:
        Process ID:             0x4
        Process Name:

Access Request Information:
        Accesses:               DELETE

        Access Mask:            0x10000
An attempt was made to access an object.
```

Is there a way to just pull out the Logn ID and Object Name?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you set the value of a single entry to the variable `$message`. The value will be a single string that contains multiple lines.

You need to search the contents of the string, and there are various ways of doing this. Here are two methods:

Pipe to `findstr`:

```
& "echo" $message | findstr /im /C:"Logon ID"
& "echo" $message | findstr /im /C:"Object Name"
```

Split by `NewLine`, pipe to `foreach` and use regex:

```
$message -split [Environment]::NewLine | foreach{if ($_ -match "Logon ID|Object Name") {$_}}
```

Note this will give you output that looks something like this:

```
Logon ID:       0x9CD04EC
Object Name:        C:\Shares\
```

You will still need to do some work to separate the values from these lines. Something like:

```
$logonID = & "echo" $message | findstr /im /C:"Logon ID"
($logonID -split "      ")[1]
```